# Three.js renders geometry wrongly

Tags: javascript, three.js

Three.js often renders unnecessary surfaces when loading `.obj` files (I haven't tried other types).
In the screenshot I attached below, there are some triangle surfaces that look like **webbed fingers**. How do I get rid of it?

I think the `.obj` file is okay because it's rendered correctly in Blender. It's exported from sketchup and it wasn't webbed before exporting.

[View in Blender](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNSRq.jpg)

[View in Three.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NeDpV.jpg)

Below is the code I'm using to load `.obj`

```
const loadManager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
loadManager.addHandler(/\.dds$/i, new DDSLoader());

const loadObj = (path, mtl) => {
  return new Promise((res) => {
    new OBJLoader(loadManager).setMaterials(mtl).load(
      path,
      async (object) => {
        scene.add(object);
        render()
        res(object)
      },
      () => {
        console.log("loading .obj, started at", new Date());
      },
      () => {
        console.log("loading .obj got error");
      }
    );
  })
}
```

I have no clue to fix this problem. I'll appreciate any kind of opinion.
Thanks.

Comment: This is not a three.js issue. I believe your geometry hasn't been converted to triangles properly. Blender allows for N-gons, which means a face can have any number (N) of edges. However, WebGL only allows triangles, which means a face can only have 3 edges. When importing N-gons into Three.js, you'll get weird faceting like you're seeing because it's guessing which faces should be triangles. I recommend you search for Blender tutorials on "how to fix Ngons".